# How to find the film with the minimum amount of actors Oracle

Tags: oracle, subquery

So I have a table called `Cast` with `film_id` and `number_of_actors` in it. I have a `film` table with `name` of film and `year.`  I need to create a sub query that will find what film has the least amount of actors starring in it and output the name of the film. I can't use joins though.

How do I do this??

So far I have:

```
 SELECT c.number_of_actors, count(*), f.name
   FROM cast c, film f
  where f.id = (SELECT min(c.number_of_Actors)
   from cast
  group by number_of_Actors;
```

I'm new to ORACLE so that's probably really wrong.  But any help would be great.

Comment: `CAST` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) in Oracle (and ANSI SQL), so it shouldn't be used as a table name -- even if it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH ranked_cast_sizes AS (
  SELECT film_id,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY number_of_actors ASC ) AS cast_size_rank
  FROM   cast
)
SELECT f.name
FROM   film f
       INNER JOIN
       ranked_cast_sizes r
       ON ( f.id = r.film_id )
WHERE  r.cast_size_rank = 1;
```

Or a different way without joins:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM   film f
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                FROM   cast c
                WHERE  f.id = c.film_id
                AND    c.number_of_actors = ( SELECT MIN( number_of_actors)
                                              FROM   cast )
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use joins (*shakes head*), you might do something like the following:

```
SELECT name, year
  FROM film
 WHERE id IN (
    SELECT film_id FROM (
        SELECT film_id, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY number_of_actors ) AS rn
          FROM cast
    ) WHERE rn = 1
);
```

Note that this will return *all* films with the minimum number of actors. If you use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()` (or, alternately, a solution based on `ROWNUM`), you'll get only one film regardless of how many films have the minimum number of actors.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you want:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT f.NAME, c.NUMBER_OF_ACTORS
          FROM FILM f
          INNER JOIN CAST c
            ON c.FILM_ID = f.ID
          ORDER BY c.NUMBER_OF_ACTORS)
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

What we're doing here is joining the FILM and CAST tables together to allow us to obtain the film name and number of actors, ordering the joined data by the number of actors so that the film with the fewest actors is returned first. Then the outer select is used to peel off the first row returned by the subquery, resulting in only a single row with the name and number of actors in the film with the fewest actors.